# Show that equation has no roots $ \in \mathbb{Z} $

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Given $ P(x) := 7x^5-23x^2 +2x -8,$ show that $ P(x) $ has no roots in $ \mathbb{Z}. $

My (primitive solution);

Assume that it exists atleast one root in $ \mathbb{Z}. $ We can then write $ 7x^5 -23x^2+2x = x(7x^4-23x+2)=8.$

$ 8 $ is then a product of 2 factors, and both must divide $8.$ We have the set of $ D_8 = \{\pm 1,\pm2,\pm4,\pm8 \}$. So we can test for every $ x \in D_8 $ and see that none of them yields 8.

Questions;

Is this a solid proof and are there any other way to show it? And does "Integral root" mean a root in $ \mathbb{Z} $?

Comment: The proof can't be said incorrect......

Comment: Except that $D_8$ is usually the dihedral group. But this is just a notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, integral root means an integer root.

The question has many answers already at this site, so let me give you just a comment, how to solve such questions in general: there is also the so-called [Rational Root Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem), which makes it easy to verify that $p(x)$ has no integral and no rational root. By the way, $P(x)$ is even irreducible over $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! The course has just begun, so we've not covered anything else of what you mentioned, I assume that we shall not use any of that.

Comment: Not my downvote, but likely because this is a dupe (of *hundreds*)  and your *comment* (not an answer by my standards) adds nothing at all novel (and isn't even good pedagogically even if it were not a dupe). I expected much better from someone who usually closes dupes of FAQs.

Comment: @BillDubuque Yes, I see that this is not an optimal answer. It should be a comment indeed. I was too quick, because of the rational root theorem, which is also often asked.

Answer (score 1):

A common technique used to prove there are no integer solutions is modular arithmetic.

Here for instance working modulo $3$:

$p(x)\equiv 7x^5-23x^2+2x-8\equiv x^5+x^2+2x+1\equiv x+x^2+2x+1\equiv x^2+1\pmod 3$

And we can use that there is no square $x^2\equiv 2\pmod 3$

Comment: Why is $ x^5 \to x $ correct?

Comment: Little Fermat theorem $x^p\equiv x\pmod p$ for $p$ prime. So $x^5\equiv x^3\times x^2\equiv x\times x^2\equiv x^3\equiv x\pmod 3$.

Comment: I'm with you! However, how come "No solutions in $ \mathbb{Z}_3  \rightarrow $ no solutions in $ \mathbb{Z} $"?

Comment: It is maybe simpler to understand with $\mathbb Z_2$, if your integer cannot be nor even nor odd, then you conclude such an integer does not exists. Same here for $\mathbb Z_3$, if such an integer exists its square must be $2\mod 3$ which is impossible, so the assumption is faulty.

Comment: Gotcha. But the other way around is generally not true though? You can have solutions in $ \mathbb{Z}_m $ but not in $\mathbb{Z} $?

Comment: Yes, it is only a chain of implications, the reciprocal may not be true. Typically $x^2\equiv -1\pmod 5$ for $x=2$, but no solutions $x^2=-1$ in $\mathbb Z$. (It is "assume an integer exists $\implies$ some contradiction in $\mathbb Z_p$, thus no integer solution").